# html, css automatically resize/adjust width to fit content

Tags: html, css

I have some html content with following structure:

```
<div class="message-container">
  <p class="message-value">someVal</p>
  <div class="message-attribute">someUsername</div>
  <div class="message-attribute">11-09-2017 12:30</div>
</div>
```

So, I want to scale my message-container up when it gets long values in `message.value` and scale it down as far as possible to min-width in the other way.

I also wan't to specify max-width for this props.

I've done this:

```
.message-container {
  resize: both;
  margin: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #80CBC4;
}

.message-value {
  resize: both;
  float: left;
  max-width: 380px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  height: auto;
}

.message-attribute {
  padding-left: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  color: #607D8B;
}
```

and message-username and message-datetime has fixed width.

Finally, I'm alsways getting max-width in my `message-container` even when it has free space to cut it down

https://jsfiddle.net/Lwrpegqe/

As you can see in jsfiddle width is too long with following content it could be shorter

Main purpose to resize block automatically

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: What Robert said. Please make it a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/); there is an editor button for that.

Comment: here you are https://jsfiddle.net/Lwrpegqe/

Comment: add can angular working demo in http://plnkr.co/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the solution.

```
.message-container {
  resize: both;
  margin: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #80CBC4;
}

.message-value {
  resize: both;
  float: left;
  max-width: 380px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  height: auto;
  display: inline;
}

.message-attribute {
  padding-left: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline;
  color: #607D8B;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lwrpegqe/2/

Comment: yes, but can you see that block message-container isn't resizing at all.. I need to have flexible block

Comment: It is because you have applied width to it. Let me make changes.

Comment: Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/Lwrpegqe/6/ Apply maximum width if you want.

Here I have floated message containers so that they don't take extra width.

Answer (score 1):

Add **display: inline-block;** to your `.message-container`

`Inline elements` only take up the space of the content. A `div` is always a `block element` unless specified.

Comment: Thanks I've changed my html structure to make inline blocks and its really works.

Answer (score 0):

Give width and height in percentage (%).
Hope it will work for you.

```
.your-class {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: How would percentage width will work here? can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

just use `w-100` in bootstrap 4 to fit to 100% width of container element